# Create a childpage in Joomla without showing it in a menu

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I would like to create a page in Joomla without showing it in a menu.
That would be easy when the URL could be from the root, e.g.
www.mysite.com/hiddenpage
I would just make a menu without module to show it and assign a menulink to that hidden menu.

However the url should be 
www.mysite.com/parentpage/hiddenpage
So the page should be linked to another existing page as a childpage but without showing in the menu.

So far this seems not possible?
Am I overlooking a feature in Joomla which would allow me to simply deactivate visibility in the menu without preventing the page from being accessed from the internet?

Or perhaps is it possible to edit or override a core component to force Joomla to allow this behaviour?

UPDATE:
Too much thinking in one direction...
The solution to do this is to edit the menu-item > linktype > css give it class "hide" (integrated bootstrap class) to just block visibility in the menu...

Comment: well, is this child page supposed to be an article? You don't need a menu item to open an article, you can just use the URL like this:
mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=YourArticleId

Comment: Yes, it is an article and it's possible to go to the page in that manner. But the URL should become www.mysite.com/parentpage/hiddenpage. This could be done by rewriting, but then my client should do all the coding (he wouldn't want to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible with Joomla.

There are several options for you to achieve the same result, I list them in order of ease.

1. Use joomla redirect component.  Simply tell the user to surf to the url he wants, he will then find it in the administrator - components - redirect, where she can insert the non-sef url.
2. Tell them to use a different prefix: i.e. create a hidden menu where they will add the direct links;

Additionally, in order to remove the id from the url you can:

1. Install simplecustomrouter extension, it should do the job out of the box but some coding may be required on your part in order for it to work properly; extremely lightweight.
2. Go for a blasoned SEF extension such as sh440sef, this will add some overhead and may require a lot of work in configuration.

Comment: Good suggestions. I was hoping that I was overlooking a feature in Joomla which would allow me to simply deactivate visibility in the menu without preventing the page from being accessed from the internet... Not possible I guess. 1. generates 301 2. a different prefix is not allowed, additionally: is it possible with those extensions to make new 'hidden' pages without a lot of work on my clients side rewrite internally, without 301? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes all the 4 solutions I proposed will do it; of course it's still a two step process, create the article, then surf to the desired url, finally assign the 404 to the article non-SEF url; Joomla redirect will be manual, while sh404 or others will try to guess and offer some support in matching the appropriate non-SEF url.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but a litle bit tricky. Try these steps :

1. Create a new two articles, name it as you wish (for example Article A and Article B )
2. Create a new menu group (from your administrator page go to : Menus > Menu Manager > Add new menu, name it as '**Hidden Menu**'
3. Create a new Single Article menu item (under the '**Hidden Menu**'), choose '**Article A**' as as the article source and type '**parentpage**' in the *Menu Title field*
4. Create a new Single Article menu item (under the '**Hidden Menu**'), choose '**Article B**' as the article source, choose '**parentpage**' menu as the parent item and type '**hiddenpage**' in the *Menu Title field*.

Now both of urls **www.mysite.com/parentpage** and **www.mysite.com/parentpage/hiddenpage** should be accessible now

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a very clever solution. However, the page would not really be a childpage of an existing page and this would ask a lot of work from my clients' side.

Comment: I don't really understand with childpage you meant. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Ah I got what you meant, so the 'parentpage' should be an article too, right? I have revised my answer, please try.

Comment: In this way the childpage would still not be a child of an existing page, but of a new fake page. The parentpage + menulink + URL already exist, the new child should be a child of that page...

Comment: Please explain what's exactly the 'childpage' you meant

Comment: A childpage is created when making a menulink and the main item level is a an other page.

Comment: Added: the main item level is an other link to a page. Not the menu-item root.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned you can find extensions to modify URLs or hide the menu items using CSS, but these can require quite a bit of work especially if this is a one-off or once in a while situation.

However, there is one way to do this with Joomla as-is and will work with any type of menu items, not just articles. These instructions assume you already have a 'hidden' menu setup.

1. In a *hidden* menu, create menu items (or move them if they already exist) for **parentpage** and **hiddenpage**.
2. Set **parentpage** as the 'Parent Item' option in the **hiddenpage** menu item. Basically, create the page/subpage structure you'd like to see in the URL.
3. On your *visible* menu, create a 'Menu item Alias' (under 'System Links') menu item. Set the 'Menu item' option to the **parentpage** (listed under the *hidden* menu).
4. Enjoy. **Parentpage** is a visible menu item. **hiddenpage** is available at www.mysite.com/**parentpage**/**hiddenpage**

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

FOR JOOMLA 3.X:
While editing the childmenu just set (under "Linktype") "Display in menu" to "no"... it's simple like that!
Here's a reference to the joomla.docs site

https://docs.joomla.org/images/6/6f/Help-3x-menus-menu-manager-new-menu-item-link-type-en.png

if link is broken just search for "edit menu linktype joomla 3" in future.

I'm glad I can return the many saved searchtime to y'all stackpeople. Go on Community!

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.